# Elm calculation using fold

Tags: elm, idioms

I just started playing around with `Elm` and `functional programming`. I really like the language but I do have trouble implementing very simply calculations.

My below code takes as input `wacc : Float` and `cfs : List Float` and should calculate a net preset value (i.e. for each element of cfs calculate cfs_i / (1 + wacc)^i and then calculate the sum of the values).

The code works but is very verbose and potentially not idiomatic.

**My main question** besides hints how to make it more concise / idiomatic is **how do I change my code to be able to accept wacc and cfs of `types Maybe`.**

Helpful for any hint / info. Thanks!

```
-- helper functions
zip : List a -> List b -> List (a,b) 
zip list1 list2 =
    List.map2 Tuple.pair list1 list2

calcDF : Float -> Int -> List Float
calcDF wacc n = 
    let
        waccs = List.repeat n wacc
        time = List.range 0 n |> List.map toFloat
        waccs_time = zip waccs time
    in
        List.map (\x -> 1/ (1 + Tuple.first x)^(Tuple.second x)) waccs_time

-- my npv function
calcNPV : List Float -> Float -> Html text
calcNPV cfs wacc = 
    let 
        n = List.length cfs
        df = calcDF wacc n
        cfs_df = zip cfs df
    in
        List.map (\x -> (Tuple.first x) * (Tuple.second x)) cfs_df
        |> List.foldl (+) 0
```

Example:

```
calcNPV [100,100,100] 0.1

-- returns 273.553719
```

Comment: Are you expecting for the cfs param to be list of maybe floats or maybe a list of floats, i.e. `Maybe (List Float)` vs. `List (Maybe Float)`? In other words are you preparing for the whole list to be missing or single values within the list missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to use Maybes.

But as you suspected, you have made the current code more complex than needed. Here's a reworking of the first function. You want n discount values, so we start by creating something with n items to loop over and then just do the calculation in the map function

```
calcDF : Float -> Int -> List Float
calcDF wacc n =
    List.range 0 n
        |> List.map (calcDF_ wacc)
calcDF_ : Float -> Int -> Float
calcDF_ wacc idx =
    1 / (1 + toFloat idx) ^ wacc
```

If you use https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#indexedFoldl you could simplify the main function just to call `calcDF_` while looping folding over `cfs` and skip calcDF altogether

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I made it quite complex give a lack of experience with functional programming (which is why I want to learn it in the first place). I came up with a new solution with some help [here](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/elm-idiomatic-code-type-maybe/5967)

Answer (score 1):

With the help from Elm discourse forum (see [here](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/elm-idiomatic-code-type-maybe/5967)) I came up with the following solutions.

NPV calculation **without** `type Maybe`

```
calcNPV : List Float -> Float -> Float
calcNPV cashflows wacc = 
    let
        time = List.length cashflows |> List.range 0 |> List.map toFloat 
        waccs = List.repeat (List.length cashflows)  wacc

        calcPV : Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
        calcPV cf i t = cf / (1+i)^t
    in
        List.map3 calcPV cashflows waccs time |> List.foldl (+) 0
```

NPV calculation **with** `type Maybe`

```
calcMaybeNPV : List (Maybe Float) -> Maybe Float -> Maybe Float
calcMaybeNPV maybecashflows maybewacc = 
    let
        time = List.length maybecashflows |> List.range 0 |> List.map (\x -> Just (toFloat x))
        waccs = List.repeat (List.length maybecashflows)  maybewacc 

        calcPV : Maybe Float -> Maybe Float -> Maybe Float -> Maybe Float
        calcPV cf i t = 
            Maybe.map3 (\a b c -> a / (1+b)^c) cf i t
    in
        List.map3 calcPV maybecashflows waccs time |> List.foldl (Maybe.map2 (+)) (Just 0)
```